# In our react js project when we use redux and when we use react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just asking if there any huge amount of js code is available in our project only that purpose we use react-redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs,

> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React component's state are no longer sufficient.

So, when you have different components that need to share the state you can go for `redux`. If your web application contains independent components which just hits any API and display data that will not be used by any other component then there is no need for redux.

Answer (score 0):

**Why use Redux?**

Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript applications. It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to test.

**Benefits of using Redux**

**1.** Redux makes the state predictable.

**2.** Maintainability  **3**.Debuggable for days.

**4.** Ease of testing. **5.** State persistence.

**6.** Server-side rendering

> One major benefit of Redux is to add direction to decouple “what
>   happened” from “how things change.” However, you should only implement
>   Redux if you determine your project needs a state management tool.

for better understanding refer to https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-redux-reasons-with-clear-examples-d21bffd5835/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use build-in React features like ContextAPI and ReactHoocks to build your own global state management system.

1. Create your Provider

```js
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) =>(
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

2. Consumer allows accessing the value  in any component of your App

```js
import { StateProvider } from '../state';

const App = () => {
  const initialState = {
    theme: { primary: 'green' }
  };
  
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'changeTheme':
        return {
          ...state,
          theme: action.newTheme
        };
        
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
        // App content ...
    </StateProvider>
  );
}
```

3. Usage inside component :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StateContext } from './state';
class ThemedButton extends Component {
  static contextType = StateContext;
  render() {
    const [{ theme }, dispatch] = this.context;
    return (
      <Button
        primaryColor={theme.primary}
        onClick={() => dispatch({
          type: 'changeTheme',
          newTheme: { primary: 'blue'}
        })}
      >
        Make me blue!
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

For better understanding refer to [State Management with React Hooks and Context API in 10 lines of code!](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)